# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/remoting/InvokerLocator runtime error

Tags: java, jboss, client

I have the client class but when the class is called, it gets a
"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/remoting/InvokerLocator" runtime error.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import org.jboss.remoting.Client;
import org.jboss.remoting.InvokerLocator;

@Named("esamDIDDClient")
public class ESAMDIDDWSClient {

    @Inject SystemProperyManager sysprop;

    private void sendMessageToJBRListener(String url, String message) throws Throwable {
        String locatorURI = url;
        InvokerLocator locator = new InvokerLocator(locatorURI);
        System.out.println("Calling JBoss Remoting Listener using locator URI: " + locatorURI);

        Client remotingClient = null;

        try {
            remotingClient = new Client(locator);
            remotingClient.connect();

            // Deliver the message to the listener...
            Object response = remotingClient.invoke(message);
            System.out.println("JBR Class: " + response.getClass().getName());
            System.out.println("Response from JBoss Remoting Listener '" + locatorURI + "' was '" + response + "'.");
        }  catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            if(remotingClient != null) {
                remotingClient.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
```

I have the *org.jboss.remoting* JAR in the IDE, also I did confirm that `InvokerLocator` class in there.

I downloaded the JAR file from [here](http://jbossremoting.jboss.org/downloads), and it is the most recent/stable one that I could find.

Am I using a wrong *remoting.jar*, or am I missing something else?

By the way, this was a using a *seam.remoting.jar*. After removing seam, I had to use a different JAR.

Comment: What's the JBoss version you're using?

Comment: @aribeiro Jboss wildfly 10

Comment: And what are you trying to accomplish? How did you manage to start the JBoss Remote Listener on Wildfly 10?

Comment: @aribeiro It was previously being used in Jboss 5.1. We are migrating the app.

Comment: That's what I thought. Because, from my understanding, Wildfly no longer uses `InvokerLocator`. You were using that with JBoss ESB or you're just invoking a simple bean? What's the type of the object you're trying to invoke?

Comment: @aribeiro Was using it with Jboss ESB function.

Comment: @aribeiro Also what do you think can be an alternative to this? At first i thought it was the problem with my IDE not getting the lib in runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When RedHat replaced JBoss AS with Wildfly, it also [replaced](http://www.jboss.org/dms/judcon/2012boston/presentations/judcon2012boston_day1track2session5.pdf) JBoss ESB with [SwitchYard](http://switchyard.jboss.org/).

Therefore, since JBoss AS7 that [there's no more support](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/207833?tstart=0) for JBoss ESB.

By the code you've posted, I'm assuming that your service is, in fact, a web service.

Therefore, I think you might want to change your code and start using a [RemoveInvoker](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/SWITCHYARD/Remote+Invoker), with [SOAP-based web service binding](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/SWITCHYARD/SOAP).

As a starting point, you could take a look at the [this](https://github.com/jboss-switchyard/quickstarts/tree/master/remote-invoker) RedHat's SwitchYard example.

Comment: Thanks i just needed someone to point me to the right direction.